# Why does mypy state "found module but no typehints..." eventhough there are actually type hints?

Tags: python, mypy

I have a service that imports modules from a directory containing a lot of packages and modules. Most of the modules in that directory are annotated with type hints.

Now, I want to check my type hints in the service with `mypy`. But for some reason, `mypy` doesn't recognize the hints in that directory and I get a lot of errors like:

> service/some.py:16: error: Skipping analyzing
> "directory.some_package.some_arbitrary_module": found module but no
> type hints or library stubs

I also already tried running `stubgen some_arbitrary_module.py` and putting the resulting `some_arbitrary_module.pyi` file in the same directory in order to check if there is something wrong with the type hints in the `some_arbitrary_module.py`.. but I get the same error.

Is there something else that can cause this kind of error?

Comment: If it's from an installable dependency, the dependency needs `py.typed`: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0561/#packaging-type-information

Comment: @MarioIshac I didn't know about that but unfortunately that didn't solve the issue :/

Comment: @MarioIshac I have to apologize. It did indeed work. Apparently, I left my brain somewhere else for a moment. I forgot to recreate my underlying python venv after I have added the `py.typed` files in the packages. If you write an answer, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, you revealed the modules you are importing are from an installable dependency. If you want to use the type hints of that dependency, it needs to have a `py.typed` per [PEP 561 - Packaging Type Information](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0561/#packaging-type-information).

> Package maintainers who wish to support type checking of their code
> MUST add a marker file named `py.typed` to their package supporting
> typing.

Here is more info from mypy's documentation at [Creating PEP 561 compatible packages](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installed_packages.html#creating-pep-561-compatible-packages):

> For example, here is a typical directory structure:
>
> ```
> setup.py package_a/
>     __init__.py
>     lib.py
>     py.typed
> ```
>
> The setup.py file could look like this:
>
> ```
> from distutils.core import setup
>
> setup(
>     name="SuperPackageA",
>     author="Me",
>     version="0.1",
>     package_data={"package_a": ["py.typed"]},
>     packages=["package_a"]
> )
> ```